# Smart Card > Kerberos > Putty > Internet

Tags: putty, kerberos, ntlm

I'm searching for a posibility to bypass the "Firewall". 
I've tried everything I know more than 2 weeks, so I ask here for a answer.

We have no admin rights and the OS is Windows Vista
There is an HTTP Proxy with NTML Authentication (only way to access the internet)

It requires a username and password
We use smart cards, in fact I have only a user number and a pin.
Port 80 and 443 are open -> I have an SSH server at home which is listening on port 443
The problem is that I need this proxy to connect to anything.

Internet access only works in IE, Chrome, Firefox when I set the proxy settings to "use system proxy settings", "proxy-autoconfig (proxy.pac)" or when I enter the proxy inside the proxy.pac file. However I can't understand where they take the username and password which the Proxy requires.

What I've tried was using cntlm to connect to the proxy with authentication (altought I have no PW and username) and PuTTY to create the SSH tunnel over port 443 whit the SOCKS Proxy which I've created with cntml.

I've never found some SSH client which includes a "use system proxy settings" function.

I belive that we use a Kerberos in order to login using the Smart Card/PIN 
Then the PC use a hided password from Kerberos in order to login on NTLM auth 
to go out to internet.

Thank a lot in andvance
Denis

Comment: Nobody can help me please  ?

Comment: Is there something wrong that i ask please ?